# C++ Overload operator for vector in class

Tags: c++, class, operator-overloading

I don't now how to ask google for answer so I'm here.
For example we have class looks similar to this one:

```
class Test
{
public:
  std::vector<std::pair<int,bool>> testList; 
}
```

So now I want overload "=" operator but for vector element in this class.

```
Test test;
---adding some elements----
test.testList[3] = true; <--- overloaded operator
```

I tried something like:

```
Test::std::vector operator= (bool status);
```

,but this make error.

Comment: You can't overload operators just for specific members of classes. Operator overload applies to a class as a whole, regardless of where it's used.

Comment: Sounds like `testList` should be a `std::map`/`std::unordered_map`

Comment: `testList[3]` is an `std::pair<int,bool>` … There is no overload to convert `bool` to `std::pair<int,bool>`. If the `int` of the `pair` is always the index, then you should use a `map`

Comment: You might be able to `Test::operator= (bool status);` and have it call perform whatever magic you require and then call through to through to `testList`'s regular `=` operator. Can't say for sure, though. Question needs more details on [what it is you really want to do](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to give you a good answer.

Comment: Thanks for answers. Now I know it's impossible to do it in that way. @ChrisMM that "int" could be any type of data. I just play right now with C++ and looking what I can and what can't.

Comment: You can overload some operators on classes outside there definition, for instance, if you were to define `std::pair<int, bool>& operator << (std::pair<int, bool>& self, bool newVal)` that could work, but it would apply to all `std::pair<int, bool>`s not just ones in you class. You cannot however overload assignment operator from outside a class definition. You could provide a custom structure instead of the pair, and implement assignment overloads for that easily enough (easy applying to C++11 or later)

Comment: [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/) -- *I don't now how to ask google for answer* -- Give google the problem you're trying to solve instead of telling google your "solution".  As the previous comment stated, it looks like you're trying to implement a key/value pair, and that is done in C++ by using `std::map` or `std::unordered_map`.